# React/Webpack - Image not loading due to wrong path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

having a little trouble with webpack loading my images. I'm getting this error:

```
GET http://localhost:1234/projects/images/KanbanCard0-70090cba.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I know that's not the path, if I take out `projects` so it will be `localhost:1234/images/Kan...` then the image will load.

This is my tree folder:

[image]

This is my component:

```
import React, { Component} from "react";
import kanban2 from '../../images/KanbanCard0.png';

class Kanban extends Component {
    render(){
        console.log(this.props)
        return(
            <div className="introWrapper">
                <h2>kanban page</h2>
                <a onClick={this.props.history.goBack}>Back</a>
                <img src={kanban2} />

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Kanban;
```

Webpack.config file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const config = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/js/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        // publicPath: '/projects/'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss?/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader' 
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: 'images/[name]-[hash:8].[ext]'
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: './index.html', to: './index.html' }
        ])
    ],
    devServer: {
      publicPath: '/',
      contentBase: __dirname + '/dist',
      port: 1234,
      historyApiFallback: {
            index: 'index.html'
      }
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

I've added a `publicPath` with `images/` and remove in `file-loader` name -> `images/`.  This will work but it adds the image outside the image folder under dist folder, so it's next to my `bundle.js`.  I would like to keep my images under `dist/images` just to be organized but I get that GET error because of the projects/images, and it should be images/kanban.....

I'm new to webpack/react, can anyone help with the issue?  your help will be appreciated!

Note:

So the word projects is in the error url -> `GET http://localhost:1234/projects/images/KanbanCard0-70090cba.png 404 (Not Found)`.  It because I'm under this page, where I want to load my image: `http://localhost:1234/projects/kanban_board`.  I do know that the image is under this path -> `http://localhost:1234/images/KanbanCard0-70090cba.png`.  Just webpack seems not to find, so it looks like it's a config/path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue, just needed to add a slash in the name:

```
options: {
                name: '/images/[name]-[hash:8].[ext]'
              }
```